# Criar e usar bibliotecas DLL escritas em C++ no .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dll

Pelo fato do .NET ser reversível, preciso codificar parte do meu programa em C++, mas ainda assim precisarei dos Windows Forms, então pensei em criar DLLs escritas em C++ para realizar algumas tarefas chave (como verificação de licença) e manter o restante do código em C#.
Estas DLLs precisarão receber e retornar vários dados, mas principalmente strings.
Realizei alguns testes com valores inteiros, e outros com strings. Não obtenho erros de compilação (nem da DLL, nem do programa que a utiliza) mas ao executa-lo a recebo os erros:

**System.DllNotFoundException** quando trabalho com strings;
e **System.EntryPointNotFoundException** quando uso inteiros;

Os arquivos DLL compilados estou colocando no diretório que informo ao importa-la, e sei que ela está sendo localizada pois os erros são diferentes quando não as coloco lá.

Estou compilando os projetos com o Visual studio, e abaixo estão os códigos usados:

**crypto.h (Cabeçalho da DLL) - C++**

```
/// crypto.h
#ifdef CRYPTO_EXPORTS
#define CRYPTO_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CRYPTO_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <string>

CRYPTO_API std::string crypto_RIPEMD160(std::string);
```

**crypto.cpp (Funções da DLL) - C++**

```
// crypto.cpp : Define as funções exportadas para a DLL.

#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "crypto.h"

#include <string>
#include <openssl/ripemd.h>

//Constantes
#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16
CRYPTO_API std::string crypto_RIPEMD160(std::string str)
{
    int tam_str = str.length();
    std::string hash;
    unsigned char* msg = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * tam_str);
    unsigned char* resp = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    //transcrever dados da string para o char
    for (int i = 0; i < tam_str; i++) {
        msg[i] = str[i];
    }
    #pragma warning(suppress : 4996)
    resp = RIPEMD160(msg, tam_str, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i++) {
        hash[i] = resp[i];
    }
    return hash;
}
```

**Projeto de destino (onde a biblioteca será usada) - C#**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace exemplo
{
    public class Win32
    {
        [DllImport(@"..\dlls\crypto.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] public static extern string crypto_RIPEMD160(string str);
    }
    public class MinhaClasse
    {
        public void teste()
        {
            string teste = Win32.crypto_RIPEMD160("TESTE");
        }
    }
}
```

Sou iniciante na programação, e realmente não encontrei algum tópico que pudesse me ajudar até o momento com este problema. Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Obs.: Os códigos não necessariamente retornam os hashes corretos, estou preocupado com as trocas de dados entre as funções.

Grato desde já!

Comment: Bom, qualquer  linguagem pode ser 'revertida' com engenharia reversa, até c++.
Para usar uma DLL de outra linguagem dentro do .net basta criar uma DLL ou uma COM 
caso seja  uma DLL basta colocar em um nuget package por exemplo, ou simplismente referenciar ela no projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está um exemplo de como passar uma string do C# para C++ e vice-versa.

```
// CDll.dll (C++ Dll)
// CDll.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#ifdef CDLL_EXPORTS
#define CDLL_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

CDLL_API int receiveString(const char* str)
{
    char chr[255];
    strcpy_s(chr, str);
    std::cout << "[C++] received string: " << chr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

CDLL_API int sendString(char* chr)
{
    const char* str = "Hello from C++";
    strcpy_s(chr, strlen(str) + 1, str);
    return 0;
}
```

- 

```
// CGui.exe (C# WinForms)
// Form1.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CGui
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport(@"CDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "receiveString")]
        static extern int sendStringToCDll(string str);

        [DllImport(@"CDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "sendString")]
        static extern int receiveStringFromCDll(StringBuilder str);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sendString = "Hello from C#";
            sendStringToCDll(sendString);

            StringBuilder receiveString = new StringBuilder();
            receiveStringFromCDll(receiveString);
            Console.WriteLine("[C#] " + "received string: " + receiveString.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta!
Porém ainda obtenho o erro abaixo:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException
  HResult=0x80131535
  Message=Não é possível realizar marshaling de 'return value': Combinação inválida de tipo gerenciado/não gerenciado (Int32/UInt32 devem estar combinados com I4, U4 ou Error).

Comment: Posta como ficou seu código pra dar uma olhada.

Comment: Irei postar como "resposta" pois não consigo colocar aqui.